# Rails, how to touch update in a has_one relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I'm reading the documentation for `touch` [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/touch) and it looks like `touch: true` can only be placed on a belongs_to relationship. However, in my world, I want the object touched to be the `has_one` association.

My data model:

```
class Tool
   has_one :product, as: :producible, inverse_of: :producible
end

class Product
    belongs_to :producible, polymorphic: true
end
```

So what I want is that everytime I update the tool, the `product` is updated too. How does one do this? I can't use `touch: true` it seems.

Also, what are `as:` and `inverse_of:` doing for me?

Answer (score 3):

As of Rails 6+, `has_one` started supporting `touch: true` in the association.

Relevant commit [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/3fe83d1dd99ac2662852da0dcfe7e91dc08ae160).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good article explaining the use of `inverse_of`: https://www.viget.com/articles/exploring-the-inverse-of-option-on-rails-model-associations

If you're looking to `touch` an associated model you can add this to your tool class:

```
after_save :touch_product

private
def touch_product
  product&.update_column(:updated_at, Time.now)
end
```

This is effectively doing the same as `touch`. It will update the timestamp in your product record without instantiating the object or running any callbacks. Source code for the `touch` method can be found here in case you're interested in reading up on it further: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/touch

Comment: it will instantiate the object because you use `product` twice

Comment: Good point @Kukunin. I've updated the answer to use the safe assignment operator, so `product` is only instantiated once